# How to "inherit" modules in Python 2

Tags: python, import, module, subprocess, python-2.x

my question is pretty simple. My goal is following - I'd like to import some necessary modules once and I want the child scripts to use those modules as well without importing. In other words, they would be able to use modules imported in their parent script. I think an example will help to understand.

I have the main script `main.py`, which might look like this

```
import os
import subprocess
import sys

...
subprocess.call(["python", "script.py", arg1, arg2])
...
```

And `script.py` is using some functions, accessible via module os (e.g. os.path.join(...)).

Is it possible to avoid `import os` in `script.py`?

Comment: No.  Each module must import the modules it wants to use.

Comment: It can be done (Python is dynamic enough to override the necessary parts)  but it should not be done -- the nice property of Python is that you can trace where each name comes from just by looking at the source code for the module unless something messes with `builtins` and/or the module global namespace.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "inherit" environment then you could use [`execfile()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#execfile) to run the module:

```
import os
import sys

# mangle sys.argv to pass arg1, arg2
# ...
# run
execfile('script.py')
```